# How to calculate the number of required flip-flop stages needed for clock-domain crossing?

Tags: fpga, timing-analysis, cdc, metastability

In a given scenario where I have two clock domains driven by a 200MHz and a 30 MHz external independent clocks, what would be the best way to calculate the number of flip-flop stages needed for proper clock-domain crossing?

At the moment, I'm assuming the calculation for the number of stages should go something like this

```
200/30 = 6.67
```

As such, I'd need 7 flip-flop stages to be able to meet the clock-domain crossing requirement. Is this a correct assumption?

The system has multiple control signals and a couple of data-buses going back and forth. The widest bus is 32-bits while the smallest bus is 24-bits.

Comment: Sounds right to enable flow control plus margin for prop.delay and latency. But could be more.

Comment: Frequency of clocks and no. of flops in synchronizer chain has no relationship like you calculated.  2 stage FF synchronizer is enough for low/medium speed designs.....but you should provide us more information on what is passed and in what direction. Is it multi bit/single bit signal etc..

Comment: @mitu-raj, thanks for the reply! Just added some more details to my inquire.

Comment: `... to meet the clock-domain crossing requirement` What clock-domain crossing requirement? Go 200->30, and you cannot of course capture all the data. Go 30->200, and only one flop is needed for the data, with 2 or 3 for control signals to meet metastability requirements.

Comment: I think you only need 3 FF's, properly connected and driven, to guarantee metastable-free signal crossing from one cock domain to another, irrespective of what the two domain clock frequencies are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number of flip flops needed depends on three things:

- target MTBF requirement
- clock rate
- ‘crunchiness’ of the flip flops

The latter point, ‘crunchiness’, is also called *metastable hardness*, and it means the flip-flop’s own intrinsic MTBF. This is related to the speed of of the flop: faster ones with shorter setup/hold times and high feedback gain are crunchier than slow ones.

More here: http://www.interfacebus.com/Design_MetaStable.html

Here too: https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee183/handouts/synchronization_pres.pdf

In most cases, with today’s logic and clock speeds in the 10s to 100s of MHz, two flip flops will yield adequate MTBF.

Related: [Why do cascading D-Flip Flops prevent metastability?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/381481/why-do-cascading-d-flip-flops-prevent-metastability)

Comment: Super useful links in this post thanks. Metastable hardness is a cool concept.